# Restore networking after failed and rolled back vpn setup

Tags: networking, server, internet, vpn, openvpn

At some point I tried to set up VPN on my home server, but couldn't get it to work. So I finally decided to roll the setup back (uninstalled openvpn) as I didn't really need it, but now the server cannot access the internet (though it is reachable from and can see the local network). By cannot access the internet I mean that I cannot ping neither ip's nor addresses or use e.g. nslookup.

I asked a colleague and he's guess was that the problem was in the routing table. The output from route on the broken system is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

and the output from another functioning machine on the same network is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

Just in case the routing table isn't the problem in this pastebin is the output of several networking commands that may be useful in troubleshooting: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6071536/ and the /etc/network/interfaces is http://paste.ubuntu.com/6071566/ (there is some static IP stuff in there that I disable during the trouble-shooting)

Can any of you help me fix the system. I will gladly provide any further needed information.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "cannot access the internet"? Can you not ping external hosts at all, or can ping by IP but not name? Apologies if I missed that in your pastebins.

Comment: Ah, you are right I don't think that information was in the pastebins. I cannot ping neither ip's nor addresses or use nslookup. I will add it to the question.

Comment: @TLE - we can no longer merge accounts automatically for you.  However, click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page with your registered account, and you'll be able to request a merge of your unregistered accounts.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like something else is reconfiguring your system after it has set up the network tables. Do you have an extra `route` call somewhere from when you set up OpenVPN, in `/etc/network/interfaces` or in another `/etc/network/` script?

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. There was no route calls anywhere there. But while looking around in the folders in /etc/network I noticed that there were still openvpn folders there and realized that I had not done a purge. After I did that, I once again have network. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.